# Why does sleeping sometimes shutdown?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, shutdown

I use the sleep button on my keyboard to suspend my PC. After it sleeps, when I hit any key, it wakes up. However sometimes the sleep button just shuts down the PC completely. Why is this happening?

Comment: @user535733 What can I do to debug? Also this hasn't happened on Windows at all (I dual boot win and ubuntu).

Comment: That's a different question. Please edit your question to ask the question that you really want an answer to.

Comment: @user535733 My question is why this is happening and how can I solve it. You suggested debugging so I asked what I need to do. That's not off-topic